# Passing Value between External Class and Windows Form

Tags: vb.net

Hello guys im having a trouble with passing a value 
External Class

```
Form1.Listbox1.Items.Add("Server Disconnected")
```

And when i debug the program and tried to connect on the server the listbox didnt show any result

Comment: `Form1`, as used in this context, is an object, not a class.  For "convenience" (and backwards compatibility with previous versions of VB), VB automatically creates a global object for each form, using the same name for that object as the form's class.  This often, however, causes confusion.  I don't know for sure, but I'm guessing that the code that shows the form is creating a new instance of `Form1` rather than using that global one.  Therefore, your code is adding an item to a different instance of the form than the one that is actually shown.

Comment: @StevenDoggart so its impossible to apply the result of a class to listbox of the form?

Comment: Of course it's possible.  You just need to make sure you're adding it to the right instance of the form.  In other words, there can be multiple copies of the same form in memory, so adding it to the wrong one won't do you any good.  You need to add it to the one that's actually being shown